# Hypernym for all of the "watching" hobbies

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

There are various hobbies that involve "watching", e.g.:

- trainspotting — looking for trains
- birdwatching — looking for birds
- stargazing — looking for stars

Is there a term which can be used to describe all of these hobbies collectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Spotters', I would say.

Years ago there was a series of little books that you could buy for children in newsagents shops in Britain. They were all named 'The spotter's book of (something)'. There were birds, aircraft, trains, wild animals etc.

I have just discovered that something similar still exists! I hope there is no rule on this site about commercial recommendations, but they make lovely gifts for kids.

http://www.usborne.com/catalogue/series/1~183/spotters-guides.aspx

Answer (score 2):

"Passive hobbies" comes to mind, as opposed to "active hobbies" such as fishing or woodworking.